# Reduce strings.xml file Size and save xml file from server to resource values folder

Tags: java, android, xml, performance, optimization

its my first post if any mistake sorry....

My Questions are:

1) Is there any way to reduce size of xml file?
    In my android project, strings.xml size is more than 10MB and i want to    reduce this size.

2) how can save files directly in resources/values/ folder from server, in running project?

If anybody know than please tell me or if there any other way which is much better than that like i searched and found bml files but i unable to convert xml to bml.

Thank You.

Comment: Are you sure, your XML file is hinderance in performance of your application?? Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/16433112/842607

Comment: yes due to this, my application seems hang devices. Secondly my application is simply a text app so i want its size might be 6 to 7 MB not more than that..

Comment: Is it some kind of book?? If so then go for webservice rather than hardcoding...!!

Comment: yes,it is a book... how can i use webservices for this?